# How to send a header+buffer efficiently with TCP/IP?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

Suppose, that I have two buffers:

- A small header (10-20 bytes)
- Payload (varies between ~10KiB - ~10MiB, but usually less than 100KiB)

I need to send this to the server. The server immediately responds when it received the buffer.

Now, if I use two `send` calls for this (one for the header, and one for the payload), I get very bad latency on windows: after the sends, `recv` (server response) arrives very slowly (40-100ms). If I turn on TCP_NODELAY for the socket, response comes faster, but I'm still not satisfied with the result (5-10ms. But server responds immediately. Ping time to the server is 0.1ms - it's on a local network).

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), that we should avoid write-write-read. But, this is the exact thing what I'm doing now. How should I solve this?

The straightforward solution is to copy the header and payload into a new buffer, and send that instead. But I'd like to avoid this, as I need to allocate a new larger buffer for this (not to mention the copy).

Another solution would be to allocate a smallish buffer (like 4KB), and send the data in chunks. But, this way, I'm not sure how this 4KB chunk will be cut into TCP/IP segments. It may happen, that the last segment will be small, so this causes a little inefficiency.

Linux has `MSG_MORE`, which may solve this issue on Linux. But I see no Windows equivalent.

What is the most efficient (fast) solution to this problem?

Comment: "copy the header and payload into a new buffer" Have you tried that? It might be that the latency is introduced by TCP slow start (or whatever it is called). A bigger send might not help in accelerating TCP startup at all. Maybe the TCP window size is the limiting factor.

Comment: You misunderstood Nagle's algorithm - it's what means you *don't* have to care how many sends you use (ignoring whatever overhead `send` itself has). You also seem to be conflating many different issues - you need to take a closer look on what's really bothering you. TCP_NODELAY is something you can use (for the last "packet" of data to be sent) if you want a "quick" response, but if 5-10ms isn't good enough for you, you probably can't use TCP in the first place, or you're micro-optimizing :) None of your solutions other than TCP_NODELAY should help with that - why would they?

Comment: @Luaan: I'm not too experienced with TCP programming. I just expect better response times. If ping time 0.1ms, then I expect TCP response 0.2-0.3ms or something like that. 5-10ms is way too high. Is it common to have such a large response time with TCP, if ping is 0.1ms?

Comment: 5-10ms isn't a long response time. Keep in mind that even just the default timer resolution of most OSes (if they have a timer resolution) is in the region of 10ms or so. Ping does an average of multiple ICMP requests, which is about the fastest thing you can do on LAN. TCP requires establishing a connection (SYN, ACK, SYN-ACK), and a confirmation of every single TCP segment sent. That's a lot of messages being sent around, in both directions. *And* you're sending a lot of data - while ping only sends a couple of bytes. They just don't compare. Don't expect to get closer to zero than 5-10ms :)

Comment: @usr: not tried yet. It would be hard to implement for my current code unfortunately. But if I get positive feedback about it, I'll do it, of course.

Comment: The main problem isn't what's absolutely possible, but what the *design requirements* are. TCP is used for reliable, bi-directional stream-based communication. It's not designed for ultra-low latency communication. Could you get a faster response time? Perhaps; there's always things you can optimize further. But is it worth your effort? Unless you have a very good reason, it probably isn't.

Comment: TCP absolutely could give you what you want (~0.3ms latency here). You might run into quality of implementation issues with the OS'es involved, though. For example, doing a quick search I found no way to make an OS kernel use a large initial TCP window. It's constantly frustrating how little control OS'es give over TCP behavior.

Comment: A possible solution would be to use a library that implements something TCP-like over UDP. Or a hybrid that tries UDP and retries over TCP.

Comment: @Luaan: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. 5-10ms is not the whole process. I connect to the server, send a little header, and a payload (now, I intentionally use a small payload, 50 bytes), and then, 5-10 ms elapses, and then I get the server response (note, I measure time very precisely with `QueryPerformanceCounter`).

Comment: @Luaan: I have a lot of communication between the client and server, so it matters whether it takes 1 or 10 seconds.

Comment: Well, that's your problem, really. Network protocols were designed with network constraints in mind. Sending a hundred requests and responses as part of one logical operation wasn't what they had in mind - it just doesn't scale. TCP doesn't send messages, it sends streams. If you want to send lots of discrete messages, TCP probably isn't the right choice (though it might be if you know very well what you're actually trying to accomplish). Optimizing to shorten the dependency chain (e.g. sequential request-response-request...) is probably going to help more than optimizing individual latency.

Comment: But again, keep in mind the *actual* constraints and requirements you have. Don't spend too much time imagining constraints and requirements you don't really have. I'm all for optimizing to get the next bit of performance out of a system, but 5-10ms per request-response pair is already extremely generous, and likely will not happen under any reasonable load and real infrastructure. If your system suffers from being this fast, you need to redesign :D

Comment: "*The straightforward solution is to copy the header and payload into a new buffer, and send that instead. But I'd like to avoid this, as I need to allocate a new larger buffer for this (not to mention the copy)*" - on Windows only, Winsock has a [`WSASend()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend) function that allows you to send multiple data buffers together.  You can use that to send the header and payload buffers together without having to merge them first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks, I'll try it out!